# .local domain not forwarding/working

Tags: server

I'm trying to set up my pi based server to be a little bit easier to access by using a .local domain.  I followed this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/167190/how-and-why-to-assign-the-.local-domain-to-your-raspberry-pi/

Upon installing `sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon` I was given the message that it already existed, which makes sense.

But when I try to connect at `raspberrypi.local`, I get a 404.

What should I do to trouble shoot this?

> $ sudo avahi-daemon
>
> Daemon already running on PID 416

Comment: Which OS do you use on your other system, from which you want to connect to `raspberrypi.local`? Windows before 10 need to have mDNS manually installed, for example, via iTunes.

Comment: To check whether the daemon is running, use `sudo systemctl status -l avahi` (or is that avahi-daemon? Try pressing tab to autocomplete the service name). This will show you whether the service is running and what messages it might have produced.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on android devices, but working on mac. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81717/pis-local-url-http-raspberrypi-local-not-working-with-android-devices?noredirect=1&lq=1