# pi's local url (http://raspberrypi.local) not working with android devices

Tags: networking, server, android

I've set up a raspberry pi as a local server (running latest version of Raspbian, latest Avahi version installed), and I would like to access the server using a local URL (http://raspberrypi.local).

I can access the server with this URL on my computer (mac), but not on my android phone nor any of my Android tablets (I used to be able in the past though). It seems the android devices are not able to resolve the IP address.

Is there a known workaround for this such as additional configuration/ or another program to be used?

Comment: There is another program to be used. Even the latest version of `Raspbian Jessie` is oldstable. You should use the latest version of `Raspbian`. It is [Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Comment: What is this other program to be used?

Comment: "You should use the latest version of `Raspbian`". Click on the link I've provided.

Comment: Actually, after checking, I'm already using the latest version of Raspbian stretch. So not solving the pb.

Comment: @Fabian I'm not sure it matters here but there are 2 servers running, one node.js and one Django, on 2 different ports.